# Does vue-cli transpile/polyfill/shim async/await for IE11?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuex, vue-cli

Using standard `vue create` template, will the following work on IE11:

```
async toggleSettings({ dispatch }) {
  if (await dispatch('confirm') { // etc }
}
```

?

Comment: I recommend you actually try it in IE 11, as the knowledge of people may be outdated on the issue. This way you are also sure that the fact that it works or not is the truth.

Comment: How would you do this on a mac @Ferrybig

Comment: Yes you can use async await with Vue, it will transpile and work in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You should check it on your own, because i don't know what template of vue-cli you use.

You need to check if `Babel` is connected to your webpack config. Read [this doc](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage) to learn more about it.

Then check the `.babelrc` file in your project directory. Check the `targets` property in this file. Editting this property you can set up browsers that should be compatible with your code.

[More info about this](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/)